# Scrollable runtime updated JPanel using MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I have been trying to create a chat client which makes use of a scrollable `JPanel` and at run-time adds `JTextField` objects to the panel.

Panel Initialising:

```
msgPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
msgPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,335));
JScrollPane msgPanelScroll = new JScrollPane(msgPanel);
msgPanelScroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
msgPanelScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
mainPanel.add(msgPanelScroll,"span 3,alignx center,wrap");
```

Adding text at run-time

```
msgDisp = new JTextField();
msgDisp.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
msgDisp.setEditable(false);
msgDisp.setText(msgField.getText());
msgPanel.add(msgDisp,"wrap,pushx,ax right");
msgPanel.revalidate();
```

But now I'm facing the following issues.  The text field aligns to the center of the panel & on adding more fields the panel accommodates as it can and does not begin scrolling.

EDIT:
MigLayout issue fixed by using pushx and ax

mainPanel.add(msgPanelScroll,"span 3,ax center,wrap,w 400,h 335") fixed the size issue

Found my answer.

Comment: Your basic problem is using "msgPanel.setPreferredSize", which will prevent the panel fro ever growing, as the preferred size is not longer been calculated by the layout managers. Consider using a JTextArea rather the. A bunch of JTextFields ... As an idea...

Comment: When I dont set the preferred size it ends up giving me a small square instead of a constant sized panel which I would prefer. Using the JTextFields because I would like to use an alignment for each line i.e. sent on the right, recieved on the left.

Comment: @MadProgrammer : thank you for guiding me in the right direction. A change to mainPanel.add(msgPanelScroll,"span 3,ax center,wrap,w 400,h 335"); solved the issue.